# How to store dynamic image at client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, azure

First of all I am sorry if I am asking which was asked previously, But in fact I didn't get anything . 
 I have some `<Div>` on my asp.net page. And using Javascript I am assigning background image from Url. Below is code

```
 divFloor.style.backgroundImage = "url(Images/FloorPlan/" + hdnFloorImgSplit[1] + ")";
```

`hdnFloorImgSplit` is array contains the url of image. This is because I am using Azure cloud service. 
 
When client refresh page or post back the page, The images are getting downloaded each time.
What I want is , I want to store it on client browser and used it from there if exists. This will save server and clients bandwidth and speed will increase dramatically.

Sorry but I am unable to find out the way. I have many images that I want to store and retried. Because of which my site is getting slow. 
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blade , They have many different methods for do that . I show you one .With localstorage Json db. 
You can use another method like Blob with XMLHttpRequest Level 2.
For more information about it , you can check this link 
-> [Saving images and filesin localStorage - javascript](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/)

### **Storing images** ( you need store in first all your pictures with localStorage.SetItem ....)

The idea here is to be able to take an image that has been loaded into the current web page and store it into localStorage. As we established above, localStorage only supports strings, so what we need to do here is turn the image into a Data URL. One way to do this for an image, is to load into a canvas element. Then, with a canvas, you can read out the current visual representation in a canvas as a Data URL.

Let’s look at this example where we have an image in the document with an id of “elephant”:

```
    // Get a reference to the image element
    var elephant = document.getElementById("elephant");

    // Take action when the image has loaded
    elephant.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // Make sure canvas is as big as the picture
    imgCanvas.width = elephant.width;
    imgCanvas.height = elephant.height;

    // Draw image into canvas element
    imgContext.drawImage(elephant, 0, 0, elephant.width, elephant.height);

    // Get canvas contents as a data URL
    var imgAsDataURL = imgCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    // Save image into localStorage
    try {
        localStorage.setItem("elephant", imgAsDataURL);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
    }
}, false);
```

Then, if we want to take it further, we can utilize a JavaScript object and do a date check with localStorage. In this example, we load the image from the server through JavaScript the first time, but for every page load after that, we read the saved image from localStorage instead:

### HTML

```
<figure>
    <img id="elephant" src="about:blank" alt="A close up of an elephant">
    <noscript>
        <img src="elephant.png" alt="A close up of an elephant">
    </noscript>    
    <figcaption>A mighty big elephant, and mighty close too!</figcaption>
</figure>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
// localStorage with image
var storageFiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storageFiles")) || {},
    elephant = document.getElementById("elephant"),
    storageFilesDate = storageFiles.date,
    date = new Date(),
    todaysDate = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getDate().toString();

// Compare date and create localStorage if it's not existing/too old   
if (typeof storageFilesDate === "undefined" || storageFilesDate < todaysDate) {
    // Take action when the image has loaded
    elephant.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
            imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext("2d");

        // Make sure canvas is as big as the picture
        imgCanvas.width = elephant.width;
        imgCanvas.height = elephant.height;

        // Draw image into canvas element
        imgContext.drawImage(elephant, 0, 0, elephant.width, elephant.height);

        // Save image as a data URL
        storageFiles.elephant = imgCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        // Set date for localStorage
        storageFiles.date = todaysDate;

        // Save as JSON in localStorage
        try {
            localStorage.setItem("storageFiles", JSON.stringify(storageFiles));
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
        }
    }, false);

    // Set initial image src    
    elephant.setAttribute("src", "elephant.png");
}
else {
    // Use image from localStorage
    elephant.setAttribute("src", storageFiles.elephant);
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but LocalStorage has size limits Starting with iOS 5.1, Safari Mobile stores localStorage data in the cache folder, which is subject to occasional clean up, at the behest of the OS, typically if space is short. Safari Mobile's Private Browsing mode also prevents writing to localStorage entirely. So basically localStorage is treated completely differently cross browser, I would suggest indexdb and store them as blogs.